# How do I check the version of the AWS SDK for iOS framework?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I don't see it in any of the header files within *AWSiOSSDK.framework*.  I'm looking for the version format used here (eg. Version 1.4.4):

http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic has been covered in a recent blog post, see [Getting Metadata about the AWS Mobile SDKs](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1L1QXV0CNECD2/Getting-Metadata-about-the-AWS-Mobile-SDKs):

> The AWS Mobile SDKs provide functionality to capture details about the
>   environment in which the SDK is executing. These details include SDK
>   version, mobile platform, and platform locale. This information can be
>   useful for diagnosing issues and to help understanding exactly what
>   you are testing/running against.

Please check the post for details and examples, e.g. in order to to capture the metadata in the debug log of an application using the [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) you apparently just need to include the following line of code:

```
NSLog( @"SDK Details: %@", [AmazonSDKUtil userAgentString] );
```

Comment: I just tried it out, and this is what I needed.  Thanks @Steffen!